# iPhone Image Not Loading at Actual PNG Size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, size, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d but there is a chance its not that which is effecting it. I am making a sprite/image like so:

```
if (score.theme == 0) {
    menuBg = @"BaseBackground.png";
}
else if (score.theme == 1) {
    menuBg = @"BaseBackground-xmas.png";
}

CCSprite *bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:menuBg];
bg.position = ccp(160, 240);
[self addChild:bg z:0];
```

However, when loaded on my device the xmas image seems to roughly 2-3 times smaller than the actual PNG file I am using in my project, all other graphics are fine, no problem, including the other background image works fine.

What might cause this to happen? Having loaded in the simulator it works fine there, but not on the device.

Comment: Just a thought - have you removed any existing versions of the app from the device? Sometimes old resources seem to persist even though a new version of the code is running.

Comment: Cool. I'll create an "answer" for the sake of prosperity/points. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes resources aren't correctly updated on the device itself (whilst only based on observational evidence if filenames aren't changed then the resource doesn't seem to be reliably updated).

As such, if you remove the application from the device and re-deploy this will force the new resources to be used.

Comment: @Josh. And everyone lived happily ever after... Happy iOS developing. :-)